# Read a line from a text file at Google Drive

Tags: linux, google-drive

It is possible to upload a big text file with words into Google Drive and somehow read it line by line from a Linux command line? Perhaps with Python?

Answer (score 0):

After the file is uploaded to Drive, you can set the sharing setting as anyone with a link can view. You can then fetch the file in Linux using curl and parse it easily.

Alternatively, you can use the [Drive SDK](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/python) to work with files in Drive.